# Laravel sqlsrv works in tinker mode but not in browser

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, freetds, sqlsrv

I have a Laravel 5 project (on a CentOS 7 machine) that connects to an external MSSQL database.

I followed the setup outlined [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2014-laravel-linux-to-sql-server-windows?page=1) using FreeTDS.

When I hit the page using a browser I get the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)`.

But when I use `php artisan tinker` and do something like `App\MyModel::get();`, it returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance with the records/models just fine.

Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

**UPDATE**
My `.env` looks like the following:

```
SQLSRV_DB_DRIVER=sqlsrv
SQLSRV_DB_HOST=host.ip.address
SQLSRV_DB_DATABASE=my_db
SQLSRV_DB_USERNAME=my_username
SQLSRV_DB_PASSWORD=my_password
```

And my `config/database.php` looks like:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => env('SQLSRV_DB_DRIVER'),
        'host'     => env('SQLSRV_DB_HOST'),
        'database' => env('SQLSRV_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('SQLSRV_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('SQLSRV_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'prefix'   => '',
];
```

My model has a connection specified: `protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';`

I'm using FreeTDS with unixODBC.

Comment: Can you add your database config (without passwords/domains)?

Comment: @Chris I updated the post with info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is blocking your outgoing connection to MSSQL.

The proper solution is to allow apache to make the connection:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

The `-P` flag makes the rule persistent, otherwise the rule is lost after a reboot.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I enabled SELinux again and run this command. Did the trick!

Comment: I found out I still had to disable SELinux because it's preventing my PHP script to use other programs/binaries like wkhtmltopdf, cpdf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't a Laravel problem but a SELinux problem. I disabled SELinux by following [this guide](http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/11142) then I was able to access my project in a browser.

I know this is not the best solution but it works for my purpose.