# Sqlsrv pdo driver extension works in tinker but not in web app

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, virtualbox, homestead, sqlsrv

I'm running Laravel with homestead and virtualbox. Via the command line, I have downloaded both the pdo_sql and sqlsrv driver extensions for php 7 and added them to my php.ini file. Using php artisan tinker, I am able to read/write to my table data just fine, but when I try to access any of the data in the actual web app I get these exceptions.

> PDOException in Connector.php line 68: could not find driver
>
> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
> could not find driver (SQL: select top 1 * from [User] where [email] = blah@email.com)

For some reason Laravel isnt seeing my drivers but tinker is. Any help from you guys on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640092/laravel-sqlsrv-works-in-tinker-mode-but-not-in-browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out tinker and laravel use different php.ini files. Though I added the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv extension to the tinker ini file located in (/etc/php/x.x/cli/php.ini). I hadn't changed the php.ini file laravel uses which is located in (/etc/php/x.x/fpm/php.ini)

After adding those extensions to the correct file and restarting my system, everything worked great. Hopes this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

If you have SELinux enabled, this might be the problem.
Check by disabling it

`$ setenforce 0`

If it starts working, permit apache or php-fpm to connect to this port

`$ semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 1433`

then enable SELinux and check that it works

`$ setenforce 1`