# Laravel - Database connection works on tinker but not website or APIs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, tinker

I am trying to point a remote database (from another IP) to my laravel setup in AWS EC2 instance. I have added the credentials in env like this (showing random credentials)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=150.150.150.150
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dev
DB_USERNAME=test-dev
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The remote IP I have added in DB_HOST. This way, tinker seems to be working fine and I can fetch the records in table but the website and APIs timeout and remaining in loading state forever.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640092/laravel-sqlsrv-works-in-tinker-mode-but-not-in-browser), and tried this command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

but it returns this message

> Could not change active booleans: Invalid boolean

I have also tried to access the mysql database through CLI in the EC2 instance

```
mysql -u test-dev -h 150.150.150.150 -p
```

And that works but not the website.

I do not have any more leads on this issue and will appreciate any pointers

Comment: Can you add your database config (without passwords/domains) for security reasons?

Comment: They are random as mentioned in my post. I wanted to show that the IP is not added as localhost. Please read the post before commenting @BismarkAsieduAsante

Comment: having a remote DB can be taxing if the application is not optimized to run the least amount of queries. Have you tried displaying ligh query based pages ? do you still have the same issue there too ?

Comment: @N69S Yes. The page I'm testing on fetches a single record from database. Tinker works fine fetching thousand records

Comment: have you checked if SELinux is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if SELinux is enabled. SELinux has to be enabled to allow some outgoing connections to work especially MySQL connection.

You can follow this guide to get it to work.
[How to Disable or set SELinux to Permissive mode](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-or-set-selinux-to-permissive-mode/)

Comment: SELinux cannot be enabled in AWS EC2 instance. Thats what I mentioned in my post again. Please read the post for the message